# How do continuous partial derivatives depend on $n$ in maximum likelihood estimation?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, moments, tensor, cumulants

I'm reading Tensor Methods in Statistics by McCullagh 1987, (P209 for this question) and I can't understand one step he uses.

He begins with the usual log-likelihood
\begin{equation*}
   l(\theta; Y) = \sum_i l(\theta;Y_i).
\end{equation*}
And then writes "It is convenient in the calculations that follow to make the dependence
on n explicit by writing
\begin{equation*}
   \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}(\beta)}{\partial\beta^r}= U_r = n^\frac{1}{2} Z_r,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
   \frac{\partial^2\mathcal{L}(\beta)}{\partial\beta^r \partial\beta^s} = U_{rs} = n\kappa_{rs} + n^\frac{1}{2} Z_{rs},
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
   \frac{\partial^3\mathcal{L}(\beta)}{\partial\beta^r \partial\beta^s\partial^t} = U_{rst} = n\kappa_{rst} + n^\frac{1}{2} Z_{rst},
\end{equation*}
and so on for the higher-order derivatives."

My question is where does this relationship come from? $\kappa$ are the cumulants, but he doesn't explicitly say what $Z$ is, but I believe they might be observations. Please can someone verify/explain how he's written the partial derivatives in this way?

Comment: It just means you rescale. For example, $U_r$ is some function, so we introduces a factor of $\sqrt{n}$ and rather writes it as $\sqrt{n} \cdot (U_r/\sqrt{n})$. The new resulting function, $U_r/\sqrt{n}$ is now denoted by $Z_r$. Therefore, $Z_r$ is simply $U_r$ but rescaled by a factor of $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Please can you explain the $n\kappa_{rs}$ in the 2nd (and further) derivations then? Why are they of magnitude n? Possibly the question I really want to know is the relationship between the partial derivatives and the cumulants and then how they depend on n?

Comment: @Nick It's likely McCullagh wrote more than one thing in 1987; I'm guessing you might mean to refer to a book (but little more than a guess; *209* can certainly occur as an article page number), in which case is this *Tensor Methods in Statistics* you're talking about?

Comment: @Glen_b, yes that's the book I'm referring to. Apologies, I might have underestimated its "street cred" so to speak.

Comment: I suspect these equations are *defining* the kappas and Z's: they are the coefficients in the asymptotic expansions of the derivatives.  It's unclear that the kappas must be cumulants.  Indeed, what exactly would they be the cumulants of?  A look at the subscript indicates they would have to be cumulants of a $p$-variate random variable $\theta:$ but those parameters are not always modeled as random variables.